# how to reduce restore time of database?

Tags: mysql, database, restore

I am using my sql database and have a database with the size of 3GB. I have an issue with the restore of database.

Means I want to restore 3GB database backup into my sql database but it takes more time (more than 24 hours). So help me to reduce to restore time.

If any query, can frankly ask me.

Thanks

**updated**

I am using mysql workbench 5.2 and restore from .sql file placed on same system.

Comment: Are your restoring on floppy disks? :-) Need more details about your configuration, exactly how you're doing the backup (how long it takes too) and the restore, and what exactly is slow in the restore process.

Comment: if the indexing is done in proper way in your database. Then most of the time it depends on your server speed and the main memory.
The configuration should be high to gain speed

Comment: so slow?What is your backup environment? Not in a lan network? please give some more backup environment.